# Comparing nodes in a linked list c

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, alphabetical

```
struct link_node
{
    char node_str[ MAX_STR_LEN ];
    struct link_node *next;
};

int compare_node( struct link_node *n1, struct link_node *n2)
{
    if(n1[0] < n2[0])
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(n1[0] == n2[0])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is the code I currently have for comparing the first letter of nodes in a linked list. The program is not running, so I want to make sure where the error in the code is. Does the code look alright? Keep in mind the error may be elsewhere in the code.

Comment: You should show the structure of your linked list.

Comment: struct link_node
    {
    char node_str[ MAX_STR_LEN ];
    struct link_node *next;
    };

Comment: @Tim Eilers  What is "the first letter of nodes"?!:) The first letter of nodes is "n".:)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments, so that everything is in one place and you can format the code, so that it is easy to read. Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please.

Comment: Since the code shown won't compile, why are you asking if it is OK? Ignoring the undefined MAX_STR_LEN (presumably you have `#define MAX_STR_LEN 32` or something similar somewhere), you've no type before `node_str`, and you can't compare structures wholesale.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `node_str` element of the `struct`. Since you pass a pointer to the struct into the function, you can access the struct's elements using `->` notation, e.g.

```
int compare_node( struct link_node *n1, struct link_node *n2)
{
    if (n1->node_str[0] < n2->node_str[0])
        return -1;
    // etc...
}
```

Usually comparison functions simply need to return "less than 0" if the first item is less than the second item, "0" if the items are equal, or "greater than 0" if item one is greater than item two. In that case you can reduce your comparison function to this:

```
int compare_node( struct link_node *n1, struct link_node *n2)
{
    return n1->node_str[0] - n2->node_str[0];
}
```

This will perform the comparison on the first character of each string. If you want to compare the whole string use `strcmp()`:

```
int compare_node( struct link_node *n1, struct link_node *n2)
{
    return strcmp(n1->node_str, n2->node_str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not right.

That is just going to compare 2 `struct link_node` objects. Since C doesn't do operator overloading, it makes no sense. You need to compare actual data inside the objects. e.g.

```
// Note: probably better to use n1-> instead of n1[0].
// node_str[0] *is* correct usage of `[]` though.
if(n1[0].node_str[0]< n2[0].node_str[0])
{
    return -1;
}
```

The whole thing can be simplified to

```
int compare_node( struct link_node *n1, struct link_node *n2)
{
    return n1->node_str[0] - n2->node_str[0];
}
```

The only difference is that now you don't just get 1 and -1 returns, just +ve, -ve or 0.

Note that this (and other answer have used `->` instead of `[]`. You might use the `[]` notation if you passed in an array of `link_nodes`, but that is probably not likely in this case.